# Using a class name string as a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection

I have an Unpack() function that takes a generic parameter T where T is a class i.e.

```
var test = Unpack<ExampleClass>();
```

The above example works fine, but I am in a situation where I need to do the same as above, but I only know the class/generic parameter name in a string. In other words, how can I do the same thing as above with:

```
string className = "ExampleClass";
```

instead of the class `ExampleClass`?

Comment: You'll need to use Reflection. You should really show more of your code, but you can get a particular method of a Type (by name) as a MethodInfo. If it's generic, then you can combine it with the name of a type and get another MethodInfo representation a particular type-specific version of the method. Then you can Invoke it. (Caveat, this is from memory, but start with GetType [or typeof)) and go from there)

Comment: Try to see if there is an overload of `Unpack` that takes a `Type` parameter instead.

Comment: If you only know it in a string, you only know it at run time. Generics must be resolved at compile time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.8)

For example

You can divide the solution to two parts. First Get the Type of ExampleClass from string representation.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("ExampleNameSpace.ExampleClass");
```

Then use the `MakeGenericMethod` to invoke the method passing the type.

```
MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Unpack));
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(this, null);
```